# Drop Shadow Effect Not Working

Tags: html, css, web

I am a rookie when it comes to CSS. Give me a php script any day!
I need some help, I've looked around the internet and have come up with a clear solution to adding a drop shadow to an image. It's not working, however. I think I have a conflict in my CSS somewhere. 
Can you please take a look at my jcfiddler and point me in the right direction please??
This is my desired effect...
[image]

[JCFiddler/z83Md/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/z83Md/1/)

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #D4E6F4;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
body:before {
    /* top shadow */
    content:"";
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 110%;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    z-index: 100;
}
.image {
    background: #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.image:before, .image:after {
    bottom:15px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:20%;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.image:after {
    right:10px;
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
    transform:rotate(3deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you're adding the shadow on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors? If you move your code to:

```
.image {
    background: #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.image:before, .image:after {
    bottom:15px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:20%;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:100px;
}
```

You'll begin to get the desired effects. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69MCk/1/)

Comment: That is a good solution, but not one I was hoping for. I've attached a picture that shows the effect I'm hoping for. Can you tweak your example to fit the picture above?

Comment: @Nathan I don't believe this is possible using only CSS. You would certainly need something like JavaScript or additional HTML elements to help make this happen! I'll see if I can mock something up

Comment: Here's a good playground for understanding `:before` and `:after` better: http://jsfiddle.net/2STx9/

Comment: [This is the page I'm using as a guide.](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/) If you view the source and the css you can see how it is put together. I'm just having trouble translating that into my current project.

Comment: Ahhhh, I was missing the div. Thank you so much!